# Rewriting query with subquery to improve performance

Tags: mysql, subquery, count

My query looks like that

```
SELECT topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers 
WHERE answers.topic_id = topics.topic_id) 
AS replies FROM topics 
ORDER BY topics.bumped DESC, topics.date DESC LIMIT 500
```

However it takes 0.6s, I'm guessing that's because of the subquery that counts answers. Any other way to achieve this effect with better performance?

Answer (score 1):

```
topics: INDEX(bumped, date) -- in that order
answers: INDEX(topic_id)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need to discuss this further.

500 is a lot of results -- more than a self-respecting UI should return.  What will you do with them?

**Also** Consider this approach:

```
SELECT  topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator, replies.ct
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  topic_id, count(1) AS ct
            FROM  answers 
            GROUP BY topic_id
    ) AS replies
    JOIN  topics  ON replies.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    ORDER BY  topics.bumped DESC, topics.date DESC
    LIMIT  500
```

It *may* run faster because of reaching into `answers` only once.

If, however, there could be zero replies in some cases, you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator, replies.ct
    FROM  topics
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  topic_id, count(1) AS ct
            FROM  answers 
            GROUP BY topic_id
              ) AS replies  ON replies.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    ORDER BY  topics.bumped DESC, topics.date DESC
    LIMIT  500
```

This does need a relatively new version of MySQL so that the derived table can automatically be given an index.

Which approach is fastest?  I can't tell; try them all.

Answer (score 0):

A small change can do little improvement in query, by count (1) instead count(*)

```
SELECT  topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator, 
    (
        SELECT  count(1)
            FROM  answers
            WHERE  answers.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    ) AS replies
    FROM  topics
    ORDER BY  topics.bumped DESC, topics.date DESC
    LIMIT  500
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` compile the same -- see `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...; SHOW WARNINGS;`

Answer (score 0):

Joining the two tables and grouping will probably be more efficient *if* you have appropriate indexes defined:

```
SELECT topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator, COUNT(answers.topic_id) AS replies
FROM topics 
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.topic_id = topics.topic_id
GROUP BY topics.name, topics.topic_id, topics.creator
ORDER BY topics.bumped DESC, topics.date DESC LIMIT 500
```

Counting `answers.topic_id` instead of `*` or `1` should stop it counting 1 for row for `topics` that have exactly zero matching rows in `answers` as it won't count NULLs.

With regard to "*if* you have appropriate indexes defined" - as others have asked, if you update the question to provide details of the table and index structure you may get a more specific/detailed response.

Comment: 1. Don't you think group by would required if u modifiy the query like. else it will give only one record for whole topic ids.
2. and count(null) will always give 0. if i am not wrong.

Comment: @HiteshRathi - [1] yes, not sure how I managed to miss the `GROUP BY` out of that. Now fixed. [2] `COUNT(NULL)` isn't what I'm meaning in that part: if the `OUTER JOIN` doesn't match anything in `answers` for any given `topics.topic_id` there would still be one wrote in the group but with columns from `answers` all NULL. You don't want to count those, but you do want something from `topics` or you would get no row for that group instead of one row with a zero count.